# Nested filter GraphQl solution in NestJs with @ResolveField

Tags: graphql, nestjs, nestjs-graphql

I need to have filter on ResolveField items with this structure.
This is my Schema First simple example:

```
type Product {
  price: Int
  categoryId: Int
  metadata: ProductMetadata
}

type ProductMetadata {
  field: String
  language: LangEnum
  productId: Int
  value: String;
}
input ProductFilters {
  price: Int
}

type Query {
  getProducts(
    filters: ProductFilters
  )
}
```

I want to query the structure like this in nestJs:

```
  getProducts(filters: {parentId: 0}, page: 1) {
    price
    categoryId
    metadata(filters: {title: "something"})
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: You can try it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-graphql-tools. This is complete solution for flexible graphql filters